# How to determine if a string from one column is in another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I need to see if a string from one column is located in another column.  What's a good way to do that please?

**Table:**

[image]

**Desired Results:**

[image]

**SQL:**

```
DROP TABLE ##SCHOOLS

CREATE TABLE ##SCHOOLS(
SchoolName   varchar(50),
ChoiceSchool varchar(50),
)

INSERT INTO ##SCHOOLS
(SchoolName, ChoiceSchool)
VALUES 
('Smith HS', 'Smith'),
('Jones High', 'Jones'),
('Eagle Elementary School', 'Eagle'),
('Hawk ES', 'Dunham'),
('No241', 'Harris'),
('Brookfield Middle', 'Brookfield')

SELECT 
ChoiceSchool
,SchoolName
FROM ##SCHOOLS
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [like](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator. For your particulare case it should be:

```
SELECT 
    ChoiceSchool,
    SchoolName
FROM ##SCHOOLS
WHERE SchoolName like '%' + ChoiceSchool + '%'
```

Comment: So the WHERE statement is reading, Wildcard > Concatenate > Column > Concatenate > Wildcard, is that correct?

Comment: @JM1 yes. `'%' + ChoiceSchool + '%'` is construction of pattern for `like` operator to check.